# C# jitter improvements in future framework versions

Tags: c#, optimization, jit

I noticed that C# jitter produces measurably slower code than C++ compiler, even if there are no "managed overhead" constructs used (such as arrays with checked indexing).

To quantify it, I timed the following simple loop:

```
public static int count = 1000000000;
public static int Main()
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        j += (i % 2 == 0) ? ((i + 7) >> 3) : (i * 7);
    }
    return j;
}
```

This loop takes 3.88s to execute (compiled with /o). Equivalent loop compiled with VC 2010 (-O2) takes 2.95s.

To verify that inferior code was actually generated I compared machine codes: created a listing (/FAs) from VC compiler, and attached a debugger to C# program (after the loop was completed).

Indeed, C++ version is using some clever tricks. For example to avoid costly multiplication by 7, there is a separate register that is incremented by 7 every loop count. C# version does the multiplication (imul) every time. There are other differences as well.

I understand that C# jitter has a lot less time to compile the code at runtime than VC at build time. But e.g. Java jitter is dynamically optimizing frequently used methods. C# doesn't seem to be doing it.

My question is: are there plans to improve C# jitter in the future framework versions?

Comment: Visual Studio RC 2012 with .NET 4.5 is available for download since yesterday. Download it (it's free) and run the same test there.

Comment: I've stopped holding my breath for new optimizations done by the jitter a long time ago. MS appears to think it's good enough in that department.

Comment: @JonHanna since .NET 4. 3.5 had some nice things, thought not too many, but after that NGen got all the love.

Comment: @harold The greater cases where tail-call elimination is done in 4.0 wasn't NGen-only.

Comment: @JonHanna that's nice. I'm not sure why you mention it though.

Comment: Your test is hand picked to show one specific case where C++ is faster than C#. I have never seen this case appear in code I've worked on, so it really doesn't matter to me what the JIT does with it. If you run your test again but focused on the memory allocator (which everyone actually uses nearly everywhere), I think you'll find the results shockingly different.

Comment: @SamHarwell - you wouldn't compare C++ and C# performance using the allocator in a performance test because in C++ you will avoid allocating at all costs.  Frankly, you should be doing that in C# as well since it gives you almost all the tools you need to do it very easily.

Answer (score 9):

Release builds, VS2008SP1, .NET 3.5SP1, average of 10 tests:

```
.NET, x86:   2.646 seconds
C++, x86:    2.652 seconds
.NET, x64:   2.352 seconds
C++, x64:    2.090 seconds
```

Classic mistakes are assuming that /o is significant, measuring jitting time, running the debug build, testing with the debugger attached so the jitter optimizer is disabled.

The x64 jitter uses the same trick you mentioned, it isn't unique to the C++ code generator:

```
00000030  xor         r9d,r9d 
... 
00000059  add         r9d,7
```

A new feature for .NET 4.5 is Profile Guided Optimization.

Future plans are never shared by a company like Microsoft and there is no point in guessing at them.

Answer (score 3):

> are there plans to improve C# jitter in the future framework versions?

Are you asking if there was in fact a secret meeting last month between Microsoft and Xamarin where it was agreed that while they'd both spent the last decade improving their respective jitters, that from now on they were sick of making things better, and would not bother any more, and MS would re-assign everyone while Xamarin would reject any submitted patches that improved the jitter?

I would say that this is unlikely, and that like every other actively-developed software project in the world, there are plans to improve it.

Besides, if I really wanted to run the code you gave as quickly as possible, I'd hand-optimise it to `return 161315136;`. Code like that can prove that implementation A is slower than implementation B in a given case, but says nothing about where the people behind either implementation should concentrate their efforts.

Comment: This code was to prove that C# jitter is to blame for C# being slower than C++, not just "managed overhead" that a lot of people (including Herb Sutter) mention. Obviously there's a lot more to performance than simple integer operations and branches.

Comment: Yeah, but aside from the results @HansPassant got with it, there's the question of how relevant it is. Is this necessarily a case for the jitter teams to put their efforts into? And if they did, would it be interesting enough for any of them to write about? I'd imagine it would go under the "and we did a few other improvements" lines you get in articles on such matters, rather than their being a flurry of blog-posts about multiplication in a loop being made faster.

Comment: I think there are significant gains to be made by improving C# jitter. I would like to see C# match or surpass Java in The Computer Language Benchmarks Game (http://shootout.alioth.debian.org). C# has native value types and it's really a shame that Java is quite a lot faster most of the time. Although they test with Mono, not MS implementation there.

Comment: I think that too. What I don't see is why you suspect that Microsoft and Xamarin might not?

Comment: .NET is over 10 years old, went through many revisions and yet not a lot has changed in the jitting department since the early days. Feel free to tell me I am wrong - but the fact remains that Java, which should theoretically be worse off, is still ways ahead. Had .NET been better performing Microsoft might not feel so compelled to make a u-turn back to C++ with Windows 8.

Comment: @kaalus: *"The benchmark game"* is Unix-only; it is comparing the JIT in Mono *(which is majorly inferior to Microsoft's)* to the JIT in Java.  On Windows, Microsoft's C# JIT tends to perform at the same level as Java's *(usually slightly faster, but that could just be confirmation bias on my part)*